# How do I change the name of an application tab?

Tags: facebook

I'm working on a facebook page for a client and with the new profiles pages starting to roll out I've come across an issue with the name of the app I created. The original profiles which most of you will see here - http://www.facebook.com/DrMartyBecker says "Welcome" as the tab name. On the new profile pages the tab says 'drMARTY', I can't find the place where I can modify the name. So i was wondering if there was a way to change this and where. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Go to edit your application and under the Facebook Integration section you should be able to edit it in this section:

[image]